# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /home/u870021518/public_html/revolt.php on line 17

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in
>   /home/u870021518/public_html/revolt.php on line 17

```
$demonsParam = ('str'=>250,
                'vit'=>1500,
                'agi'=>1500,
                'def'=>10000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вы хотели объявить массив, это делается вот так:

```
$demonsParam = array('str'=>250, 'vit'=>1500, 'agi'=>1500, 'def'=>10000);
```

Если PHP 5.4+ можно использовать короткий синтаксис:

```
$demonsParam = ['str'=>250, 'vit'=>1500, 'agi'=>1500, 'def'=>10000];
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь!)